# Change if else condition into array

Tags: android, arrays, if-statement

How can I change this coding into an array? Because I found this step is too long. I'm new to this so can you help me. Thank you.

```
if(num2 == 1)
    {
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
        if (num1 == 1)
        {
            display2.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
        }
        else if (num1 == 2)
        {
            display2.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
        }
        else if (num1 == 3)
        {
            display2.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
        }
        else if (num1 == 4)
        {
            display2.setImageResource(R.drawable.four);
        }
        else if (num1 == 5)
        {
            display2.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code works, so why bother?  It's fast enough and gives you the right result.  "Don't fix it if it ain't broken".

Comment: On a more relevant note, https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can't you store an `R.drawable...` type rather than `num1`?

Comment: @AleksG thank you sir. But the problem is that I have to code both the variables num2 and num1 until number 10. So won't it be long sir?

Comment: A `switch` statement would be slightly cleaner, but I'm not sure the long code is unavoidable.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over your `R` object, I'd strongly advise to simply store the `drawable` members as an array to begin with. But if you insist,

```
Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[...];
drawables[1] = R.drawable.one;
drawables[2] = R.drawable.two;
...
if(num2 == 1) {
    int index = (num1 >= 1 && num1 < drawables.length) ? num1 : 1;
    display2.setImageResource(drawables[index]);
}
```

Although it may be better to just stick to your current code or use `switch`. It's verbose, yes, but pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks sir. But this is only the part of the coding. I will have to code this till number 10 for each variable. So won't it be long?

Comment: @amln_ndh You mean the initialization? How would you avoid it when they're class members and must be explicitly named to be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a [`LevelListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html).

You define the Drawable like so:

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/one />
    <item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/two" />
    <item android:maxLevel="3" android:drawable="@drawable/three" />
    <!-- ... -->
</level-list>
```

Either in XML or in your code, set the background of `display2` to this Drawable.

You can then simplify your code to:

```
if(num2 == 1) {
    display2.setImageLevel(num1);
}
```